# How do I port a shell script to Perl?

Tags: perl

This is a shell script , How do I accomplish the same thing in Perl?

```
prfile=~/sqllib/db2profile

profile()
{
if [ -f $prfile ] && [ "$prfile" != "" ];
then
        . $prfile
else
        read -p "Enter a valid Profile : " prfile
        profile
fi
}
profile
```

Here it checks for the profile file , if found it executes it with `. $prfile` else it again asks user for the proper profile file

**Update**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $profile = "$ENV{'HOME'}/sqllib/db2proile";
# default profile

while (not -e $profile) { # until we find an existing file
  print "Enter a valid profile: ";
  chomp($profile = <>); # read a new profile
}

qx(. $profile);
```

This worked. I want the home directory to be dynamic rather than hardcoded as they differ for different machines. I'm just trying to accomplish with Perl what I have achieved with shell.

Comment: Which, specific, part of the script is giving you problems? The first this script does is to assign a value to a variable. If you don't know how to go about that then you really need to start with a basic Perl tutorial before asking for help here.

Comment: **~/sqllib/db2** is like **/home-direc/sqllib/db2** in shell , when i do **@prfile='~/sqllib/db2'**; , its not working , when i do **`~/sqllib/db2`**; even this not working , how do it do it

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? `@prfile='~/sqllib/db2'` should give no visible output (unless you `use strict` **which you should** in which case it will error because you forgot `my`). `~/sqllib/db2` should error because it doesn't mean anything in Perl. (Any why on earth are you using an array?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objectives, I don't think you can use perl to accomplish this because perl will be running as a child process and it can not change the environment of your shell (it's parent process). Maybe this would work for you (untested, off the cuff)?

```
prfile=~/sqllib/db2profile
if [ -s "$prfile" ] ; then
   . "$prfile"
else
  while true ; do 
    read -p "Enter a valid Profile : " prfile
    if [ -s "$prfile" ] ; then
       . "$prfile"
       break;
    fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: The code i have pasted in working fine in my script , thimg is im trying to rewrite in perl

Comment: I understand, but, you can not modify your shell's environment in perl.